# Getting data using Retrofit and inserting to SQLite Database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, retrofit2

I have just started working with Kotlin. I have successfully got data from an API using Retrofit. I have to insert that data in SQLite. But I am not able to get a particular data from the response.

Here is my code:

```
apiInterface.enqueue( object : Callback<List<Movie>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Movie>>?, response: Response<List<Movie>>?) {

            if(response?.body() != null)
                recyclerAdapter.setMovieListItems(response.body()!!)

            response?.let {
                for (i:Int in response.body()!!) {
                    recyclerAdapter.setMovieListItems(response.body()!!)
                    val myMovieList = response.body()

                    val myMovie = myMovieList!!.get(i)


                    var movie = MovieDatabase(myMovie.title, myMovie.image)
                    db.insertMovieData(movie)
                }
            }

        }


        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Movie>>?, t: Throwable?) {

        }
    })
}
```

Here is my insert method:

```
fun insertMovieData(movie: MovieDatabase) {
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    var cv = ContentValues()
    cv.put(COL_FIRST_NAME, movie.name)
    cv.put(COL_LAST_NAME, movie.image)

    var result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME_MOVIE, null, cv)

    if (result == -1.toLong())
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    else
        Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: show me the error

Comment: > I have successfully got data from an API using Retrofit.
> But I am not able to get a particular data from the response.
How is it related to the database, then?
If you have a JSON response that contains all the data you need, then you can just use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to convert JSON to DTO-s in a form of POJO-s and use https://github.com/google/gson to actually deserialize JSON into DTO instances (e.g., using https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson)

Comment: you are doing to much functionality in "onResponse" and in wrong order. Hard to test it!
You should get out from here to another class / function , like a "MyResultManager" and there insert into database and after that load the UI from database, in my oppinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've successfully, got back `List<Movie>` from the response body, just put the response into a `List<Movie> myList`.

`List<Movie> myMovieList = response.body();`

Then loop over it to get the values you need.

`Movie myMovie = myList.get(0); //To get first Movie in list and so on`

Then as per your Movie class use the getter methods to fetch further details of the movie; For example:

```
String imgURL = myMovie.getImage();
String movieName = myMovie.getTitle();
```

Build a SQLite DB from Room Persistence Library (it's simpler and easier than directly using SQLite database) and add the movie information there. Read - [Save data in a local database using Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room). Or, continue with your SQLite database, and call the respective `insert` method and query you've built with the data you got in imgURL and movieName.

You can also have a special method in your database handler class which could take entire myMovieList in one go and iterate over it inserting the values into database one by one.

My code examples are in Java, but, you should be able to write your Kotlin equivalent ones.

Here's the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) on Room Persistence Library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but I am getting error in for loop. Loop parameter mismatch. I have updated the response in the question. Please check.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes. I might've been vague with my words. I'll reword it.

Comment: @USER9561 Define myMovieList before the loop and use that list variable in the loop instead of response.body().  And see if that fixes your problem.  

I do not know Kotlin. Also, I'm not sure if this is the way you'd run your loop, `for (i:Int in response.body()!!)`. The java equivalent should be; `for (int i=0; i<myMovieList.size(); i++)`.

 If you still have problems with your loop, I'd suggest you post a fresh question with kotlin tag, asking about the loop, to get a better response regarding how to setup your loop to perform the insertion task.